# Prove that $\|\mathbf{X}\|_\sigma \leq \sqrt{rank(X)} \|\mathbf{X}\|_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-rank

How can I prove the inequality ?

$$
\|\mathbf{X}\|_\sigma \leq \sqrt{rank(X)} \|\mathbf{X}\|_F
$$

where 
$\|\mathbf{X}\|_\sigma$ is the trace norm (sum of singular values of $\mathbf{X}$) and $\|\mathbf{X}\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm of $\mathbf{X}$.

The only thing I can see is that $\|\mathbf{X}\|_F \leq \|\mathbf{X}\|_\sigma$

Comment: @Antoine my question is not about the spectral norm, but about the nuclear norm.

Comment: I am so sorry! I have deleted my answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both norms are unitarily invariant. So, by singular value decomposition, you may assume that $X$ is a (possibly rectangular) diagonal matrix and the inequality in question reduces to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality about the vector containing the singular values of $X$ and the all-one vector.

Comment: Let me elaborate on what I understood from your answer, $\|e\sigma\|^2 <= \|e\|^2\|\sigma\|^2$, where $e$ is the vector of $1^s$. Since singular values will be non-zero only till rank, $\|e\| = rank(X)$ ?.

Comment: @Shew No, trim away the zero part of $\sigma$ first, so that $e$ and $\sigma$ are vectors of length $\operatorname{rank}(X)$.